# Mentioning the Army Reserves at new job?

Tags: ethics

I had a successful interview today and start in a couple of weeks. However, I also plan on sending my Army Reserves application off in a couple of days. Due to the number of days this requires you to be off, one big 2 week block , I'm not sure if I should mention that I've applied when I start.

Should I hold off my application for a couple of months first and settle in first?

Comment: James, which country are you in. Army reserves, and the laws around your service vary significantly

Comment: I'm guessing he's British from the wording and the 2 week block part for reserves.

Comment: US Army National Guard and Reserves also do a two week annual ADT (active duty for training).

Answer (score 7):

I would hold off anything that might be disruptive to the crucial time when I'm new in a job and making the impression with my colleagues and bosses that will be the most lasting one.

You want to go in looking, keen, committed, and happy to be there, not passing time between personal stuff. Give them a chance to at least remember your name.

Comment: Knowing which country this is in is important. Army reservist often have some legal protections from discrimination in their civil job. Knowing which country affects the protections offered.

Comment: @MichaelShaw Doesn't matter what legal protections there are, I'm talking about human impressions and initial networking. Start of a job is a crucial time.

Comment: Isn't this a bit unethical? You'd basically be willfully withholding information from your interview. Is that out of scope for these questions?

Comment: @DoritoStyle I'm interpreting Kilisi's answer as suggesting the OP wait a little while before signing up for the Army Reserves.

Comment: I got the same impression as @Eric. To be honest, it would not make sense, at least IMHO, to accept job offer, then go on and sign up to activity that I know will impact job I already accepted. OP might be able to do so further down the line or he could get told it's not possible with current work arrangement. If you sign up, then have to commit to out of work activity for 2 weeks, I suspect employer will not be amused.

Answer (score 4):

**Tell them once you've been accepted and know the dates you'll be gone.**

If you haven't even applied yet, then there's no guarantee you'll be accepted. (Correct me if I'm wrong and you know they will accept you.) At this point, there isn't anything to tell that's helpful to them, especially if you aren't sure of the training dates yet.

If you *are* confident that you will be accepted and you know the dates, then yes, you should tell them when you start. If there's regular training in addition to the initial two weeks, then you should provide a calendar of that to them, too. I would make sure you know your rights in your country first, though, in case they try to pull any illegal shenanigans.

Comment: They are starting I two weeks. The hiring decision has already been made.

Comment: My bad, I somehow forgot that bit after reading the answers. I'll edit shortly.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends.**

If you are joining the National Guard or the U.S. Army Reserves, you will be protected by federal law from prejudice and mistreatment by any employer.  Still, you may not want to give the *perception* of having misled your employer. That said, you may not want to tell them that you might be gone, perhaps even out of the country, at the discretion of people in Washington D.C. who have pencils behind their ears.  And you may not want to mention ***national emergencies***.

As a writer above has recommended, wait until you actually have a date for Basic Training/AIT/weekend drill.  Keep in mind that some units will want you to attend drill before you attend your initial training.
Most drills take place on the weekends.  Will you be working on the weekends? Is there anyone else at your prospective job who is a weekend warrior?

On the other hand, you may want to inform your prospective employer that you are going to join up.  **If the training directly applies** to your prospective job, that could be a huge feather in your cap.  Some military jobs have training which is extremely expensive on the civilian side.  Another important factor is whether you will get a **security clearance**.  This can also be of vital interest to a future employer and make you much more valuable.